# Highlight matching words in the checklist file only

Tags: vba, ms-word, cpu-word

Allen Wyatt posted this code on his website, "Paul has a document that he needs to check against a word list contained in another document. If the document being checked contains one of the words in the list, then the word in the document (not in the word list) needs to be highlighted by being made bold."

I want to modify this code to highlight matching words between the active document and checklist file only in the checklist file, but not in the active document, is this possible?

```
Sub CompareWordList()
Dim sCheckDoc As String
Dim docRef As Document
Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim wrdRef As Object

sCheckDoc = "c:\checklist.doc"
Set docCurrent = Selection.Document
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
docCurrent.Activate

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
End With

For Each wrdRef In docRef.Words
    If Asc(Left(wrdRef, 1)) > 32 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = wrdRef
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next wrdRef

docRef.Close
docCurrent.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```vb
Dim docList As Document, docText As Document, wd As Variant

Set docList = Documents("Document2") 'list of words
Set docText = Documents("Document1") 'some body of text

For Each wd In docList.Words
    With docText.Content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = Trim(wd.Text)
        wd.Font.Bold = .Execute
     End With
Next wd
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reply
I am not an expert in VBA, but I edited your macro to following but does not work
Sub CompareWordListV2()
Dim docList As Document, docText As Document, wd As Variant


Set docList = Documents("C:\Users\James\Documents\2.docx") 'list of words

Set docText = Selection.Document 'some body of text

For Each wd In docList.Words
    With docText.Content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = Trim(wd.Text)
        wd.Font.Bold = .Execute
     End With
Next wd

End Sub